# Migrate a Debian 7 server with mdadm to Hyper-V

Tags: debian, raid, hyper-v, software-raid, migration

I have a physical server running Debian 7 with mdadm configred to have 2 300GB disks in RAID-1. I need to import that server into a VM to be run with Hyper-V. If it hadn't RAID I think it would be quite straightforward to achieve this from Hyper-V import tool, but I'm worried that mdadm would create some issues.

Unortunately on that server I have an old and heavily customized application that would cost me weeks to rebuild the same environment starting from scratch.

Someone knows a way to do it?

- Both machines are in the same LAN
- On Windows Machine there is obviously room to save all data

Thanks in advance,
Moreno.